# Why do these errors appear on my wordpress site?

Tags: errors

On my /wp-admin/ page I get this error:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mytheme_admin_bar_render' not found or invalid function name in /home/rgomme1q/public_html/geoffrey/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406
```

And on my edit page I get this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/rgomme1q/public_html/geoffrey/wp-content/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/shailan.DropDownMenu.php on line 239
```

Apart from these errors, the site functions perfectly. Also the files mentioned are never touched by me and are in their original state. I guess the errors come from a typo in another file, but how do I determine which file is the culprit?

Comment: The culprit is not the file, is the author(s) who developed without `WP_DEBUG` enabled...

Comment: Have you tried disabling the plugins? Seems the second error is coming from a plugin named 'dropdown-menu-widget'. Try disabling the plugin one by one and try to find out the culprit one. In most of the cases, the upgraded version of WordPress conflicts with the plugin or vise versa.

Comment: Correction: people develop plugins and themes for free, it's up to the user to make sure they work properly, and to provide feedback to the authors and to help improving the code.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a callback function for something. My guess is that somewhere something is trying to use a function named `mytheme_admin_bar_render` as a callback but that function has not been defined. Something like...

```
add_filter('something','mytheme_admin_bar_render');
```

... possibly but there are many, many possibilities.

[`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) your `wp-content` folder for `mytheme_admin_bar_render`, or use an IDE that can do source code searches over entire directories. It is hard to say what to do when you find it. If it is a filter, as above you can probably just comment it out or delete it.

```
// add_filter('something','mytheme_admin_bar_render');
```

If it is something more complicated, you may need a different approach.

Without the code for the plugin (and I can't find it) solving the other issue isn't going to be easy. Chance are that the plugin is trying to do something like ...

```
foreach ($somearray as $k=>$v) {
 //...
}
```

... where `$somearray` has not been set or is set to `false` or some other data type that you can't `foreach` over. Look for the nearest `foreach` to that line in the error and try to analyze what is happening. Something like...

```
if (isset($somearray) && is_array($somearray)) {
    foreach ($somearray as $k=>$v) {
     //...
    }
}
```

... would probably do it.

Comment: Thanks :) I was able to find and fix the mytheme_admin_bar_render error! I can't find anything for the other error though. Shailan dropdown plugin has whitespace on the line given in the error. How would you solve that one?

Comment: The plugin link is this one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/ I will try to find the foreach you mentioned :)

Comment: Hmm. No foreach even near that line, and the line self is empty. All other foreaches look good. I still think it has something to do with another file. But how do I know where to search for it?